# File access permissions error/completeFileProtection issues in iOS 15

Tags: swift, ios15

I am currently testing an existing production app in iOS 15 beta . I have observed that access to an existing plist file is sometimes denied on iOS 15 even though this has always worked without problems on previous versions of iOS. The file protection level is set to .completeFileProtection, so this is how the file is created:

```
try data.write(to: dataFilePath, options: .completeFileProtection)
```

The file is created as expected, however I get the following error when I try to access on iOS 15.

> The file “myfile.plist” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
> permission to view it

The line throwing the exception is:

```
data = try? Data(contentsOf: myFilePath)
```

Please has anyone experienced this or does anyone know any resolution of the problem? Thanks a lot for your help.